# How to change the CPU usage mode programmatically.

Tags: android, cpu-usage

In Samsung galaxy s3 user is able to limit the usage of CPU from power mode.
My app needs a lot of CPU and I'd like to turn it on in onResume and turn it off in onPause methods.
I know that I can force the screen to stay on with [PowerManager.WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) but
this is not affects on CPU as I understood. 
So is it possible to change the CPU mode programmatically.
Any suggestions and comments are welcome.

Comment: When you say 'my app needs lots of cpu' how have you determined that?

Comment: app does complex operations and maybe the 1ghz cpu is not enough for example.

Comment: Still not sure if you need it. You could be doing something that can be broken up in to threads, or long running in which case you can use a partial wake lock. If you are running a game and performance isn't good with the CPU limiter on, you could always detect you are on a S3 and ask user to turn it off.

Comment: @MorrisonChang ask only by showing some notification when app launches first or there is a way to detect the CPU mode for Samsung s3 and only after that ask?

Comment: Not aware of any API to detect CPU mode officially. Still as it is a user option, mention it someplace so the user will turn it off when running your app.